# How to correctly create cross platform paths with Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, cross-platform

I have a project and I build path from token strings using path join e.g.

```
 let myPath = path.join('root', 'path01')
```

Normally I develop on a POSIX dev machine so no issues at all... but
(Unexpected) is that if I run the app on windows it will build paths backslashed

And finally the app is deployed on a POSIX system so it will produce possibly wrong expectations (if starting to develop from windows)...

What's the best way to treat paths with nodejs/javascript so to have them working on all platforms?

Comment: One question to consider is whether users on different platforms may work on the same set of paths in some way. If not, `path` is probably best. OTOH if there are for example collaboration features, you may want to use a single normalized representation of paths internally (e.g., POSIX even on Windows) and convert them to platform-specific format when actually interacting with the filesystem.

Answer (score 4):

Use Upath (Universal Path), a drop-in replacement to Node's `path` library:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath

I've just discovered it, and it's **brilliant**.

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> What's the best way to treat paths with nodejs/javascript so to have them working on all platforms?

You are already using the best way, which is by using the `path` module functionality.

> Normally I develop on a POSIX dev machine so no issues at all... but (Unexpected) is that if I run the app on windows it will build paths backslashed

This should be expected, because that's the whole purpose of the using `path.join`. When your code runs, `path.join` will join your path using the correct delimiter for the operating system, i.e. `/` on POSIX and `\` on Windows.

> And finally the app is deployed on a POSIX system so it will produce possibly wrong expectations (if starting to develop from windows)...

There won't be an issue, since you are running on POSIX, `path.join` will create a path suitable for your POSIX system.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few friends that will help, I'd start off by looking at the Node `path` object and its methods.  `path.delimiter` in specific to start with, but there may be some short-cut methods that can help you as well.

https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_delimiter